# Does a 2D PDE becomes an ODE on the diagonal line y=x?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

For the following quasi-linear PDE for $u(x,y)$:

$$a(x,y)\partial_x u +b(x,y)\partial_y u+c(x,y) u=0\tag{1}$$

If we study the behavior on the diagonal line ${\color{red}{y=x}}$, then substitution ${\color{red}{y=x}}$ into (1) leads to:

$$\left[a(x,x)+b(x,x)\right]\partial_x u +c(x,x) u=0\tag{2}$$

If we study the behavior on the other diagonal line ${\color{blue}{y= - x}}$, then substitution ${\color{blue}{y= - x}}$ into (1) leads to:

$$\left[a(x,-x)-b(x,-x)\right]\partial_x u +c(x,-x) u=0\tag{3}$$

Is this correct?

Comment: No, $\partial_y u(x, y)$ becomes $\partial_y u(x,x)$ after substitution.